# The Definition of Convex Surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $\Sigma$ be a $C^{\infty}$  compact surface in $R^3$.

(1)If the tangent space of every point lies the same side of $\Sigma$, we call $\Sigma$ convex surface.

(2)If the Guass Curvature $K>0$, we call $\Sigma$ ovaloid.

(3)If $\Sigma$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$, and the union of interior of $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma$ is convex, we call it a (3)-surface.

> What is the relationship between convex surface and ovaloid? How is the situation in higher dimension?
>
> In $R^n$, if $S$ is a compact convex set, then the boundary of $S$ is homeomorphic to a sphere. So is the definition (3) equal to the definition (1)?

Comment: A [capsule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsule_%28geometry%29) is a convex surface that is not an ovaloid, since the Gaussian curvature is equal to zero along the cylindrical surface.  Note that a capsule is not a $C^\infty$ surface (it is only $C^1$), but it can be modified slightly to make a $C^\infty$ surface by "smoothing" the transition from cylinder to hemisphere.

Comment: Thank you. A convex surface is not necessarily an ovaloid. Is an ovaloid is a convex surface?

Comment: I suspect that the answer is yes.  I also suspect that (1) is equivalent to (3) as long as the surface is homeomorphic to $S^2$.

Comment: I think that an ovaloid is a strict convex surface i.e it does not contain line segments.

Comment: For example the cylinder is a convex surface and is not an ovaloid.I think that every ovaloid is a convex surface.

Comment: Finally, a convex set is not a convex surface and vice versa. The convex surface is a certain subset of the boundary of a convex set with non-empty interior. A convex set means every pair of points are joined by a line segment in the set.

Comment: I find a paper "On the Total Curvature of Immersed Manifold" by S.S  Chern. If $\Sigma$ is a compact surface in $R^3$ with nonnegative Guass Curvature, then it is a convex surface. However, it cannot be generalized into higher dimension. If Guass Curvature is positive, we can make it in any dimension. And this is called Hadamard Theorem.

Comment: I have some more specific questions. Is a Guass Curvature of convex surface nonnegitive?@Jim Belk @Sane

Comment: Can you take an example about your statement: Finally, a convex set is not a convex surface and vice versa.@Sane

Comment: The sphere $S^{2}$(the boundary of a closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$) is a convex surface but as a set it is not a convex set since the line segment joining any pair of points of $S^{2}$ does lie in $S^{2}$ while the closed ball is a convex set.

Comment: This closed ball is a good example of a compact convex set and hence its boundary is homeomorphic to a sphere.

Comment: So is (3) equal to (1)? @Sane

Comment: for compact surface, I think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) and (3) are equivalent (this also holds in higher dimensions).

Suppose (1) holds. Each tangent plane divides the space into two   half-spaces, one of which contains $\Sigma$. Take the intersection of all such halfspaces: it is a convex set containing   $\Sigma$ and its interior. Show that it is equal to the union of $\Sigma$ and its interior. To prove that $\Sigma $ is homeomorphic to $S^2$, use radial projection from an interior point.

Suppose (3) holds. Convexity implies that for each $p$ there is a supporting plane: a plane that passes through $p$ and has the set on one side. Show that this plane is the tangent plane at $p$.

(2) implies the other properties (in 3 dimensions), but this is not trivial. The key words are *Hadamard's ovaloid theorem*

(1)-(3) do not imply (2); counterexamples are found in comments.

(1)-(3) imply $K\ge 0$. Indeed, suppose $K<0$ at some point $p$. Choose a system of coordinates so that $p$ is the origin and  the tangent plane at $p$ is the $xy$-plane.   Then the surface $\Sigma$ is locally the graph of a function $z=f(x,y)$ with a saddle point, because the Hessian determinant of $f$ is negative ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature#Alternative_formulas)). This contradicts (1).