# Can a part of the spherical surface be convex?

Tags: convex-geometry

In my opinion, the line between two arbitrary points on the surface of a sphere is never part of the surface (the line is inside of the sphere). Hence a part of the spherical surface can't be convex.

But I have read it differently.

E.g. here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/1969084?seq=1

or here: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183500307

Comment: Please tell us where you've read this.  It's impossible to address your question without that context.

Comment: Different things can be meant by "convex surface" vs "convex set". Compare to the use of "convex" for the graph of a concave up function. You might find the discussion on this question helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623728/the-definition-of-convex-surface

Comment: Thanks @BrianBorchers I added two links

Comment: Thanks @halrankard thats it :)

Answer (score 1):

"Convex on the surface of the sphere" means convex with respect to geodesics (great circles) on the sphere.

From the first paragraph of the linked article:

> By  a  convex  region  on  the  sphere  we  mean  a  region  such
> that  any  great  circle  arc  of  length  less  than  $180°$,  whose
> end  points  lie  in  the  region,  lies entirely  in  the  region